# Имплементация функционального интерфейса

Tags: java, дизайн-языка, лямбда-выражение

Понимание интерфейса, как конструкции языка, до некоторых пор было мною вроде бы как усвоено. Столкнувшись с лямбда-выражениями это понимание рискует быть пересмотренным. Что я имею ввиду?

Интерфейс позволяет "объединить" в некотором смысле относительно разные классы и работать с ними под определенным углом (интерфейсом). Так или иначе, чтобы им (интерфейсом) воспользоваться, его необходимо имплементировать.

Функциональные интерфейсы, которые определяют один метод, ведут себя иначе? Их не нужно имплементировать, достаточно создать ссылку на них и присвоить этим ссылкам лямбда-выражение?

Мне интересен сам масштаб возможностей, который здесь открывается. Выходит **просто ссылка** на функциональный интерфейс внутри любого класса способна манипулировать объектами любого класса?

Comment: Ну, лямбда-выражение и есть имплементация. Оно раскрывается в целый класс под капотом.

Comment: Это нужно, чтобы там где вы раньше писали анонимный класс с одним методом (`Runnable`, слушатели, компараторы, предикаты) можно было использовать лямбда-выражение. Условно говоря (а по факту так и есть в определенных условиях), лямбда выражение превращается в анонимный класс.

Comment: Лямбда - это, грубо говоря, компактная запись анонимного класса. Имеются кое-какие особенности. И требование к функциональному интерфейсу иметь один метод (не дефолтный) - это для того, чтобы была однозначность, что именно реализует лямбда. Очевидно без этого и лямбы никакой не было бы. Ссылка на функциональный интерфейс ничем не отличается от ссылки на обычный интерфейс. Потому что интерфейс он и функциональный тоже интерфейс

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто как пример, что же такое лямбда в Java

Лямбда

```
new AccidentsRequest(result -> {if (!result.has("error")) parseJSON(result);}, true);
```

ТРАХ-ТИБИДОХ, АХАЛАЙ-МАХАЛАЙ!!! И лямбда превращается... В анонимный класс!

```
new AccidentsRequest(new AsyncTaskCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTaskComplete(JSONObject result) throws JSONException {
            if (!result.has("error")) Content.this.parseJSON(result);
        }
    }, true);
```

Фактически лямбды в Java - это такой синтаксический сахар для анонимных классов с одним методом.

Comment: `@rjhdby спасибо, очень наглядно.